# Angular - How to define animation parameters default values?

Tags: angular, angular-animations

I am working with Angular animations, and to improve my animation, I need to use parameters. To do so, I did [as this answer suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46003758/8800147), with **interpolation**.

Here is what I have for the state :

```
state('position', style({ transform: 'translateX({{translate_X}}) translateY({{translate_Y}}) skewX({{skew_X}}) skewY({{skew_Y}})' }))
```

**component.html**

```
<div class="iris" [@move]="{value: triggerValue, params: {translate_X: translate_X, translate_Y: translate_Y, skew_X: skew_X, skew_Y: skew_Y}}"></div>
```

And here is the error I didn't manage to solve :

> ERROR Error: The animation trigger "move" has failed to build due to
>   the following errors:
>    - state("position", ...) must define default values for all the following style substitutions: translate_X, translate_Y, skew_X,
>   skew_Y
>       at InjectableAnimationEngine.AnimationEngine.registerTrigger (...)

***So where and how should we define Angular animation parameters default values ?***

Comment: view this:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41966673/parameter-in-to-animation-angular2

Answer (score 14):

I'm not sure if it's too late, but the as the console says, you must add a default value for the animation and you can do it by adding

```
{params: {your_variable_name: 'default_value'}}
```

in you animation state, like this:

```
state('in', style({height: '{{maxHeight}}px',}), {params: {maxHeight: '0'}})
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: 'very' minor criticism - your example solved my problem for me, however, using the name maxHeight was a bit misleading for me.

Other than that, thanks!